# Scheme - function to count occurrences of atom in argument

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I'm new to scheme and trying to learn functions. I want to create a function where I can count all occurrences of the atom "a" in an argument. This is what I have written so far. I'm not sure what to write in the third condition. Please help out.

```
(define (count-a arg)
   (COND
     ((null? arg) 0)
     ((eq? arg 'a) 1)
     ((list? arg) ( ___ + ( ___ count-a arg)))
     (else 0)
     
))
```

This is the output i want:

(count-a 'a)
1

(count-a  'aa)
0

(count-a '(a))
1

(count-a '(ab c)
0

(count-a '(a (b c) (c (d a) a) (((a b)))))
5

Comment: How confident are you that the pattern in your third condition has a suitable form?

Comment: A list has two components, a head and a tail. It looks like you want to count all the a's in head, all the a's in the tail, and add them. Your skeleton expression is however not well formed, since in Scheme you would write (+ ....) And also the recursive function call is (count-a something) without a term before count-a

Comment: @coredump or it's `( _red..._ + ( _ma.._ count-a arg))`. no sharp-quoting in Scheme. :)

Comment: is this a homework? do you want us to give you an answer or a hint? have you learned about higher-order functions yet, like `filter` or `fold`? ------ also, `(count-a '(a (b c) (c (d a) a) (((a b)))))` should be 4, isn't it?

Comment: @Will Ness I am afraid you are right :'(

Answer (score 2):

`(___ + ( ___ count-a arg))` doesn't seem right to me. Remember Scheme is a prefix language. It's `(+ 1 2 3)` instead of `1 + 2 + 3`.

In the third one you have two lists parts. eg. `'(a a)` so you need to call `count-a` on the `car` and on the `cdr` of the list and add the results together. eg. `(count-a '(a a))` should give the same result as `(+ (count-a 'a) (count-a '(a))`

Good luck

Comment: it is right, just not for a newbie. :) `+` is a function argument to a "functional" (in old-FP-speak).

Comment: @WillNess It would be confusing to demonstrate `map` in this answer :-o

Comment: much less confusing yet than `reduce`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

**Solution:**

```
(define (count-a  arg)
  (cond ((null? arg) 0)
        ((not (pair? arg)) 
          (if (equal? arg 'a)
              1
              0))
        ;; At this point we know arg is a pair, and we recurse.
        (else (+ (count-a (car arg)) (count-a (cdr arg))))))
```

**Test:**

Here are the tests you specified, compressed into a single line.

```
;; Chibi-Scheme REPL - other implementations might look different.
> (map  count-a '(a aa (a) (ab c) (a (b c) (c (d a) a) (((a b))))))
(1 0 1 0 4)
```

You didn't say what you want to happen if `arg` is a dotted pair. But let's check it out just for fun.

```
> (map count-a '((ab . '()) (ab . a) (a . a)))
(0 1 2)
```

So when I run your last test on my code, it yields 4 where you expected 5. I maintain that my code is correct and your test specification is incorrect, as there are only four instances of `'a` in the argument of `count-a`.

**Discussion:**

You specified in your headline that the thing the `count-a` function will be counting is an atom. So you have to check whether `arg` is an atom or not. Since Scheme doesn't have an `atom?` function, I'll assume that an atom is anything that's not `'()` and not a pair. (This is consistent with the atom function of Common Lisp, as well as other Lisp dialects.)

Since your code already deals with `arg` being `'()`, we only have to deal with  `arg` being, or not being a pair.

If `arg` is *not* a pair and `(equal? arg 'a)`, then `(count-a arg)` equals 1. Else, it equals 0.

If `arg` *is* a pair, we can recurse into `car arg)` and `(cdr arg)`, however deeply nested `arg` may be, and increase our count whenever we find an atom that equals `a`.

Hope that helps.